# My Sappho questions: best way to handle

Tags: discussion, specific-question, migration

I have recently asked a few questions about reconstructing Sappho. I have been told that they would "get better exposure" on Latin.SE. For the future one, I will definitely move to asking them over there, but what about those I have already asked? There are currently four of them:

- [Ode to Anactoria, about l. 3 of stanza 2](https://literature.stackexchange.com/questions/2690/about-l-3-of-the-second-stanza-of-sapphos-%e1%bd%a8%ce%b4%e1%bd%b4-%ce%b5%e1%bc%b0%cf%82-%e1%bc%88%ce%bd%ce%b1%ce%ba%cf%84%cf%89%cf%81%ce%af%ce%b1%ce%bd-ode-to-anactoria);
- [Sappho 94, safopoemas' completion: who came up with it, what was it actually, and how supported is it](https://literature.stackexchange.com/questions/2704/who-put-forward-this-completion-to-sappho-94-and-what-is-it-actually-supposed-t);
- [Possible authorship dispute on Sappho's epigram for Aithopia the little girl](https://literature.stackexchange.com/questions/2721/about-sapphos-epigram-for-the-little-girl-aithopia-first-line-manuscript-trad);
- [About "Hector and Andromacha"](https://literature.stackexchange.com/questions/2731/about-sapphos-hector-and-andromacha-poem).

For the first one, I have already [received an answer here](https://literature.stackexchange.com/a/2692/1662) and [posted a follow-up](https://latin.stackexchange.com/questions/4574/what-are-our-sources-for-longinus-de-sublimitate) on Latin. For the last one, I kind of answered it myself by seeing how the lines from the extra scrap join nicely with those from P.Oxy. 2076, so I don't think I'll cross-post. I would, however, like to cross-post the other two. Is that OK? Is there a better idea? I was thinking there might be an option to migrate them to Latin. Is this the case? Otherwise, I could just copy-paste the questions into Latin SE and close the posts here, but what would the appropriate reason be? The upvotes seem to say they have been received well, so I guess `off-topic` and `unclear what you're asking` would not fit the bill. It's not a `duplicate` of anything. I don't believe it's `too broad` or `primarily opinion-based` either. So what should I do about this? Just cross-post and leave the posts here alone?

Comment: First of all, please don't cross post them, at least not yet. I was discussing this with a Latin mod, but we hadn't reached a conclusion. I also don't think it should be closed here, as it's a perfectly fine collection of questions. In fact, the newsletter with the top posts of the week was basically all your questions :P. The users on Latin.SE are aware of the question, but you may want to drop into their chat room and see if anyone can help you in there. They're also not easy questions, so it might take a while before you get an answer, even on Latin.SE.

Comment: @Mithrandir what chat room? Could you give me a link? I mentioned closing to avoid having some answers here and some over there in case I cross-posted. I'll wait for you two to reach a conclusion. Update me when you do.

Comment: [Here](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/36130/conloqvivm) is a link to Latin.SE's main chat. Based on [Latin.SE's meta posts](https://latin.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/159/reposting-latin-questions-from-linguistics-se-which-could-be-answered-better-her), it *looks* like they'd be fine with you cross posting.

Comment: For reference, [here's a meta answer from a Latin mod that addresses this situation](https://latin.meta.stackexchange.com/a/302/12).

Comment: I have seen some of those comments about Latin being a better site for your questions, and they seem to come from only one user (as far as I can tell), for whatever that's worth. I haven't used the Latin site, so I can't tell you how the Latin community would take your questions, but your questions are perfectly on-topic and in-place here. They are questions about Literature, essentially, that also have an ancient language aspect to them. (Note also that for this reason, if I understand the scope of Latin correctly, they may not all be on topic there.)

Comment: That said, there's no reason to do anything about previous posts on Literature. As I said, they're perfectly within the scope of this site, so they can be left where and as they are. Cross-posting is something that should be taken up on both sites' metas; most sites in the network will be okay with cross-posting if there's reason to assume that one site will have access to a base of users with different areas of expertise. (I do not know the policies of Lit or Latin offhand.)

Comment: @Shokhet I dropped into the Latin chat room and they seem to be favorable to cross-posting there.

Comment: @Mithrandir How is that discussion going :)?

Comment: @MickG - I had to leave, but the conversation is happening here, on Latin.SE's meta, and your questions, so it's slightly confusing :P

Answer (score 5):

You could try doing a AB test: post half of your questions on Latin, post the other half on Literature, and see which site gets you the best results.

That said, if you want good answers, I think you're past the point where you can get help from an internet website. You need to seek out some professors at a university, and you need to spend a good chunk of time in a university library. By all means continue to post questions on Stack Exchange: I find that sometimes the act of writing a question helps me gather my thoughts, and it's a good way to promote your project. But you aren't going to get answers on Stack Exchange that will help you move forward on your project. If you are serious about moving forward with your project, again, you need to find professors and a university library.